# Vue axios promise scope is not binding to current component

Tags: vue.js, axios

How to bind functions in methods object. I believe if I use arrow function, it should auto bind with current object. However, it has its own scrope. Therefore, I cannot update data variables after http get request.

This is my **customers** component.

```
 import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        customers: 'temp ',
        loading: 'false',
        error: null,
      }
    },
    created () {
      console.log(this)//this is fine 
      this.getCustomerList()
    },
    watch: {
      '$route': 'getCustomerList'
    },

    methods: {
      getCustomerList: () => {
        console.log(this)
        axios.get('/api/customers')
        .then((res)=>{
          if(res.status === 200){
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

This is result of console.log(this)..

[image: result of console.log(this)]
**This is my app.js file**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import Customers from './components/Customers/Customers.vue'

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: __dirname,
  history: true,
  routes: [
    { path: '/customers', component: Customers }
  ]
})

new Vue ({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
methods: {
  getCustomerList () {
    console.log(this)
    var that = this
    axios.get('/api/customers')
    .then((res)=>{
      if(res.status === 200){
          //use that here instead of this
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: this is already in wrong scope which is not bind to component scope.

Comment: @user3882878 made few changes, it works like this in my code.

Comment: hmm.. i should not use arrow function. Thanks I just realized

Comment: I've tried declaring the method using function() {..}, using arrow function, I've tried passing arrow functions and function() {...} to the then method. I've tried the var that = this trick. None of it works. Inside the then handler method, "this" is not in scope, nor can the function see variables from the lexical scope (like the "that" variable). Perhaps a compatibility problem in versions of axios (0.15.3) and vue (2.2.1) and vueify (9.4.0) I am using?

Comment: @DouglasA.Seifert It should had worked, Can you add your relevant code and post it in a question, to be able to comment on it.