# Can't set property inside of Axios promise in Vue JS

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

i'm trying to use VueJS and Axios to make an HTTP request to a Laravel backend to get some JSON and then use the JSON to update an errorMessage property on my Component.

```
            Axios.post('/api/login', {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }).then((response) => {
                this.errorMessage = response.message;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
```

The problem is that it's not being able to reference `this.errorMessage` for some reason, am i doing anything wrong here? I'm correctly making the HTTP request and the JSON response comes back just as expected if i `console.log` it, but when i try to manipulate `this.errorMessage` it says that it's undefined even though i've already manipulated it with success elsewhere...

Here is the entire code for this component

```
export default {
    methods: {
        submitForm: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            Axios.post('/api/login', {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }).then((response) => {
                debugger;
                this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
        }
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            errorMessage: null,
            email: null,
            password: null
        }
    },
    components: {
        'error': Error
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

The original request is correct, fat arrow functions should keep the value of `this`, the issue was with Chrome's Debugger, which showed the values to me as `undefined` even though they weren't... Sorry for the silly question, i hope this will help other people coming across this kind of issue.

Comment: It's a context issue. Show some more code.

Comment: @JonatasWalker i've updated the question with the entire code for this particular component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue axios promise scope is not binding to current component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754346/vue-axios-promise-scope-is-not-binding-to-current-component)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Axios.post is closer function so property define within it looks like private under closer function.

You have to define variable outside closer like this :

```
//this will pick your data.
let self = this;


Axios.post('/api/login', {
     email: this.email,
     password: this.password
  }).then((response) => {
  self.errorMessage = response.message;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
```

Also if `response.message` is undefined then use `response.body.message` or the returning variable from laravel.

Comment: Yup. that's it @MandeepGill thank you :)

For some reason the debugger in chrome keeps saying it's `undefined` when i hover over `self.errorMessage` and that completely threw me off cause i'd tried that before actually.
But despite Chrome saying it's `undefined` it works regardless.

Comment: It could be possible you have a cache, in chrome there is network tab in developer tools open that tab check disable cache and keep developer tools open then refresh and let me know if still this issue is.

Comment: This answer is wrong. This is exactly what arrow function are for; they keep the outer context.

Comment: @JosephSilber you're right... it was the damn debugger... sorry

Answer (score 0):

The response's data is available under the `data` property:

```js
this.errorMessage = response.data.message;
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, the problem is the `this.errorMessage` which is undefined, so it's setting a string to undefined, so it does nothing at all. I don't quite know why this.errorMessage is undefined since i'm using fat arrow functions... i might be confused with something here.

Comment: @JoãoSerra - it's `undefined` because `response.message` is `undefined`. Use `response.data.message` instead.

Comment: i did, i'm using the `debugger` to check the values it's no longer undefined but the problem remains, like **Jonatas Walker** noticed it's a context issue for sure, i'm just not entirely certain how i can fix it.